# Android Facebook SDK UserSettingsFragment crashes when paused before it finishes its tasks

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I use `com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment` to manage login/logout to Facebook in my app:

```
UserSettingsFragment userSettingsFragment = new UserSettingsFragment();
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if(session==null || session.isClosed()){
    userSettingsFragment.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
}
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, userSettingsFragment, "userSettingsFragment");
```

It seems to login/logout properly, but when I start this `Fragment` when I'm already logged and pauses it (by replacing the `Fragment` for instance), it crashes. It seems that it has some thread running, and when it's finished, it need the `Activity` and it's not there anymore, so it crashes.

It looks like a bug to me, or am I missing something?

```
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment UserSettingsFragment{420c3a08} not attached to Activity
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:579)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment.processImageResponse(UserSettingsFragment.java:383)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment.access$7(UserSettingsFragment.java:379)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment$2.onCompleted(UserSettingsFragment.java:370)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at com.facebook.widget.ImageDownloader$1.run(ImageDownloader.java:161)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-18 12:16:58.345: E/AndroidRuntime(18068):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: looks like a bug, please file it here (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) with repro steps.

Comment: Thanks, I already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug, indeed. Here's [my bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/213991312097350)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar behavior. If I close the UserSettingsFragment after logging in, but before the image updates, i get a no activity attached crash.

I am using the following workaround. In UserSettingsFragment.java, I modified the processImageResponse(String id, ImageResponse response) to check if the fragment is added:

```
    private void processImageResponse(String id, ImageResponse response) {
    if (response != null && UserSettingsFragment.this.isAdded()) {
        Bitmap bitmap = response.getBitmap();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(UserSettingsFragment.this.getResources(), bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0,
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_profile_picture_width),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_profile_picture_height));
            userProfilePic = drawable;
            userProfilePicID = id;
            connectedStateLabel.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null);
            connectedStateLabel.setTag(response.getRequest().getImageUri());
        }
    }
}
```

Updating the SDK directly is obviously not ideal, but neither is letting my app crash:-)